# Can "incessantly" be used in situations that are not annoying?

Tags: meaning

Is "incessantly" only used when the incessant thing is **annoying**? Can it be used in other situations?

Example 1: "Incessantly" with **annoying** situation (ie correct):

> I could not sleep because the dog was barking incessantly

Example 2: "Incessantly" with **pleasant** situation (is it correct?):

> His friends were delighted because he was incessantly singing with his beautiful voice

Comment: *Constantly* can be used to express the same negative implications as *incessantly*.  *Constantly ringing my doorbell.*  *Incessantly ringing my doorbell*.  They are often used to describe  behavior that is repetitive.

Comment: Agree, but *constantly* can also be used without negative implications. I am not sure if this is also the case for *incessantly*.

Comment: (2) doesn't sound right to me. Oxford says that the adjective _incessant_ only applies to unpleasant things.

Comment: Would you use "ceaselessly" instead for (2)?

Comment: @KateBunting - Please take a look at MichaelHarvey's comments below. He seems to disagree with you.

Comment: Michael says, correctly, that some dictionaries say that _incessant_ is only used for annoying things, others do not. Oxford Languages does say so. I agree that usages like _incessant kindness_ sound OK; _he was incessantly singing_ doesn't sound to me like something the neighbours would be happy about, however beautiful his voice!

Comment: Context is everything. A baby's incessant screaming is probably worrying to its parents, and annoying to the other passengers on a plane, and a nurse's incessant care and help is undoubtedly gratefully received by a hospital patient.

Answer (score 4):

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/incessant) thinks so:

> continuing for a long time without stopping in a way that is annoying
>
> *incessant crying*
> *the incessant flow of traffic across the bridge*

Other dictionaries don't seem to make that point, but that is the way I use the word.

Comment: His incessant eye for detail made him an excellent choice for editor-in-chief. No?

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther ... much to the annoyance of the copy writers?

Comment: I would use 'incessant' about actions rather than qualities,

Comment: "This thesis would have not been possible without the incessant help and support of my partner and ally, Gabriel"

Comment: It looks like there is no agreement on the answer...

Comment: The OED doesn't mention the negative connotation, and its old citations (up to around 1700) do not have that connotation. But at least one, and possibly all three of its later citations do.

Comment: The word origin is from latin "cessare". "Incessantly" means "not ceasing", so originally it was not restricted to annoying situations. I am not native so I don't know if it is awkward when it is employed in for example pleasant situations.

Comment: @goalie - although 'incessant' is often used about things that cause annoyance, it can also be used about good things, e.g. support, encouragement, kindness, etc. Everyone can agree about that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - see the above comment from Kate Bunting who seems to disagree with you. Thank you.

Comment: @goalie - Cambridge (Oxford's great rival) Dictionary says 'never stopping, **especially** in an annoying or unpleasant way' - note that 'especially' does not mean 'always'. Some dictionaries say it is only used for annoying things; others do not. You can find plenty of examples of incessant approved-of things on the web, and these are not errors - 'Continual, persistent, incessant prayer is an essential part of Christian living and flows out of humility and dependence on God'

Comment: @goalie Seneca (a philosopher) said '"Incessant goodness conquereth evil men'. Belgian refugees who were welcomed in Hereford (UK) during World War One, after their country was invaded by Germany told the mayor of that town in 1915, 'We shall never forget your incessant kindness to us during the time we have been here'.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHarvey. Note that my question refers to "incessantly" and not "incessant", though I guess that your comments also apply to "incessantly".

Comment: @goalie - They do. The adjective or the adverb. Both.

Answer (score 1):

Of itself, **incessant** seems to be neutral but, in collocations and general current use, the never-ending quality, even in "He was incessantly pleasant", seems to be chiefly annoying, thus negative.

From the OED, on the positive side, I found

1564   W. Bullein Dialogue against Fever Pestilence f. 109v *To thee, oh heauenlie father, be incessaunt honour and glorie.*

1682   J. Norris tr. Hierocles Golden Verses 3   *They incessantly enjoy the divine felicity.*

However, in the first the nuance was "eternal" and the 1682 quote is not idiomatic in current Modern English.

Comment: I am not native and not a linguist, but I tend to think that in old English the word was neutral because of the neutrality of its latin origin, whereas in modern English it has evolved to become mostly negative in use, with the neutral/positive uses being possible (but unusual and maybe even awkward) because of its origin still dimly manifesting itself in the "collective language consciousness".